On Single Product Page in woocommerce how to move some text
I hope I ask this question correctly.
I am trying to move Product Condition: Refurbished up under Availibility: In Stock.

<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}
/**
 * Adds the human readable product condition
 * to the product meta section.
 *
 * @return string
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'product_condition_display_product_meta' );
function product_condition_display_product_meta() {
    global $product;
    // Retrieve the product condition for this product
    $product_condition = product_condition_return_selected_condition( $product->get_id() );
    if ( $product_condition ) {
        // Filter for the product condition label
        $label = apply_filters( 'product_condition_display_label', __( 'Product Condition: ', 'product-condition' ), $product->get_id() );
        ?>
        <span class="product_condition_wrapper">
            <span class="product_condition_title"><strong><?php echo esc_html( $label ); ?></strong></span>
            <span class="product_condition">
                <?php
                switch ( $product_condition ) {
                    case 'other':
                    case 'new-other':
                        // Retrieve the custom product condition if it is set in the product settings
                        $custom_condition = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'product_condition_custom_condition', true );
                        echo esc_html( $custom_condition );
                        break;

                    default:
                        echo esc_html( product_condition_options( $product_condition ) );
                        break;
                }
                ?>
            </span>
        </span>

I am editing this from a plugin Product Condition for Woocommerce.
I bolded the Product Condition and changed SellerRefurbished to Refurbished. Can not seem to get this last part to work.
This part of the code from single-product-page.php:
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'product_condition_display_product_meta' );

I believe I need to remove (remove_action) it and somehow replace this woocommerce_product_meta_end with different priority to raise it up underneath Availibility:inStock.

There are two options.

You can indeed remove the action and add it again.
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'product_condition_display_product_meta', 25 );

Then, add it back in at a different hook:
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'product_condition_display_product_meta', 15 );

This will move the product condition display up in the single product page, just below the availability section.
The code snippet is for the functions.php file or a custom plugin. It retains the original function's functionality while changing the position at which it's hooked into the WooCommerce single product summary.

Another way to achieve the same result without directly manipulating the PHP actions is by using custom CSS to reposition the product condition element. This method doesn't alter the HTML structure or PHP code but simply adjusts the visual layout.
.single-product .product_meta .product_condition_wrapper {
   order: -1; /* to the start */
   margin-bottom: 10px; /* margin as needed */
}




I apologize Christian.
Those things did not work for me.

I am using the astra theme.
